# git branch publishing with and without pull request

Tags: git, github

*I am migrating from TFS. I have been avoiding git. I am trying to get the hang of it now.*

*I am using the command line.*

I have a repository that has a branch, I can publish changes to that branch, I was doing this mostly for backup. All was fine, I could merge and push to master when needed.

I have another repo. Today I noticed that when I push to my secondary branch on this repo and I visit the repo (master) on github it prompts me to create a pull request from the publish changes on the branch.

The question is, what is different about these repos and/or branches.

What have I done?

Comment: My guess is that GitHub is just making a friendly suggestion that you bring the changes from the secondary branch into master via a pull request.  You don't necessarily need to do this, but it would be the most likely course of action at some point.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am so craving knowledge and unsure of myself a github suggestion blew my mind. ― Wonderful.

Comment: Stay hungry, stay foolish :-)